# jQuery animate with opacity on images show them at different speeds with same animate time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

I've a menu with some items and an image background is shown/hidden at mouse enter/leave events on those items. There is a base background image that doesn't change (instead of a white background). The problem is that some images are shown slower than others with the same animation time.

Live example [here](http://pg02test.netai.net).

And jQuery code that I use:

```
// getting selectors

        var $cont_imgs = $('img', '.animacion_img');
        var selectors = {
            $lis: $('li', '#cssmenu'),
            $imgs: $([
                $("#inicio"),
                $("#canalcolor"),
                $("#sada"),
                $("#casas_de_madera"),
                $("#riveira"),
                $("#azalea"),
                $("#contacto")
            ])
        };

// applying some css

        selectors.$imgs.each(function () {
            $(this).css({position: 'absolute', top: 0, opacity: 0}).hide();
        });

// registering events

        selectors.$lis.each(function (i) {
            $(this).on('mouseenter',function () {
                selectors.$imgs[i].animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
            }).on('mouseleave', function () {
                $cont_imgs.each(function () {
                    $(this).stop(true, true);
                });
                selectors.$imgs[i].animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000);
            });
        });
```

As you can see, the time is 300ms for all images but for some reason it doesn't work for all. And I can't see what's happen here. I need some help.

Thank you .)

Comment: May be its effects according size of image file. Like small size image take less time to shown and large size image take more time to shown.Last image size is 73.2kb its takes less time and third last image size is 194 kb.

Comment: Yep, I thought about it, but the images are already cached. It shouldn't matter.. Thanks anyway .)

Comment: yeah but its takes time even you use them with cached.Once try to use with same size files.

Comment: Still thinking that it no makes sense. Think about it. Images are cached. The image is already there. I only play with its opacity. The image is not restored from cache, it is already painted.Anyway, I recompressed and uploaded all images to demonstrate it. Take a look to the [live example](http://pg02test.netai.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the same time for showing and hiding images. For example:

```
selectors.$lis.each(function (i) {
        $(this).on('mouseenter',function () {
            selectors.$imgs[i].animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
        }).on('mouseleave', function () {
            $cont_imgs.each(function () {
                $(this).stop(true, true);
            });
            selectors.$imgs[i].animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500);
        });
    });
```

It seems to be working. Try on your own on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yV9Eg/).

Comment: Tested and it works like a charm. I still don't know why reason doesn't work as expected with different animation times but the effect is the desired. Thank you very much.

Comment: @pg02, my pleasure. Actually, I don't know either, but it is interesting to investigate.

Comment: Uhm I tried to report as bug at jquery bug tracker but I get a forbidden page. I will try later. Thank you again for your help @Gino